# How do I restrict relations between entities to a parent entity?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relations

I have a multi-vendor database for my e-commerce application. Below is a simple interpretation of my table and relation structure.

**Table: stores**

- store_id (PK, AutoIncrement)

**Table: categories**

- category_id (PK, AutoIncrement)
- store_id (FK)

**Table: packages**

- package_id (PK, AutoIncrement)
- store_id (FK)

**Table: categories_packages**

- category_id (PK, FK)
- package_id (PK, FK)

I need to restrict relationships between package and category to their respective store. For example with my current table structure `store A` categories can have `store B` packages, this is not allowed in my application.

**My question:**
Can I adjust my database design to restrict such behavior, or do I continue to use my application to conduct validation checks?

Comment: Wrong scheme. `categories` and `packages` must refer to `categories_packages` which refers to `stores`.

Comment: @Akina , I don't understand. Are you saying that I need a store_id FK within the bridging table?

Comment: *Are you saying that I need a store_id FK within the bridging table?* True.